# Automating Quad Remesher Process in Python Failing!

Tags: python, scripting, remesh

Hi,

I am really stuck with the development of my workflow I am trying to create and need some support to get this working :)

Objective: To have a bunch of meshes inside a single blender file, then run quad remesher over each mesh one at a time and save out the new retopol of the mesh. Or to load in a mesh one at a time and run the quad remesher and save it out

The Issue: I have tried creating this process using several variations in thinking and i know if I create 3 separate scripts and run then one at a time to load a file/files in, do the remesh and finally save out then doing this process one at a time manually works. What I really want to do is either run these scripts in sequence via the command line or in sequence in blender.

However whenever I try to do this it appears that quad remesher is creating problems as the new retopol of the mesh never gets saved out, i have a suspicious this is due to the context in the scene not being updated until all scripts have been executed and thus when exporting there is no new retopol in the scene yet to export.

I could really use some expert help here, this is my latest attempt to get it working but I am currently on iteration 18 or 19 and this is getting annoying:

Step 1: I run a Windows Powershell command in the Blender directory to invoke a Blender background job to run 3 scripts in sequence.
Step 2: Script to load in the mesh file:

```
import bpy
import os

# Deselect all objects in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Delete all meshes in the scene
for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

# Delete all objects in the scene
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)

# Path to the directory containing the FBX file
fbx_dir = "[DIRECTORY PATH]"

# Name of the FBX file to import
fbx_file = "[FILENAME].fbx"

# Join the directory and file names to create the full path
fbx_path = os.path.join(fbx_dir, fbx_file)

# Import the FBX file
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_path)
```

Step 3: Script to run the remesher:

```
import bpy

# Get the active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Set the context override
override = {
    "active_object": obj,
    "selected_editable_objects": [obj],
}

# Set the desired props
qremesher_properties = {
    "target_face_count": 1000,
    "adaptivity": 0.7,
    "use_smooth_normals": True,
    "preserve_volume": True,
    "timeout": 120,  # increase the timeout value to 120 seconds
}

# Call the operator using the context override
with bpy.context.temp_override(override=override):
    bpy.ops.qremesher.remesh(qremesher_properties)
```

Step 4: The script to save out the new file:

```
import bpy
import time

time.sleep(20)

first_mesh = next((ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type == 'MESH'), None)
if first_mesh is not None:
    filename = first_mesh.name + ".fbx"


# Define the filepath of the exported FBX file
export_filepath = "[DIRECTORY PATH]{}".format(filename)

# Export the selected objects as FBX file
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=export_filepath, use_visible=True)
```

I even added some wait functions in to see if it required some time to process the remesh but it still doesnt work and the output file does get created, but I only see the original mesh in that file and the retopol is missing :(

Thanks!

Comment: Python 101 : don't modify a list while iterating over it. You can add this prompt to Chat GPT, I think it will understand. :) Also you don't want to use `time.sleep`, use [application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) instead

Comment: Thanks @Gorgious for the foundational advice, much appreciated :) Not solved the problem, any ideas on how to fix the problem and get the outcome I want?

Comment: @Anixan Did you have any luck with it? I have the same problem

Comment: I’m looking at automating this again. Searching around. I don’t know if the fact that quad remember is an external program and the addon is just a go between